# How to use GitHub Desktop with AWS CodeCommit and AWS SSO profile?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, github-desktop, aws-sso

I have enabled SSO for my organization and created a user. The user has admin rights to a sub account and is able to clone a repo via terminal. The problem is when I am trying to use GitHub Desktop to clone (or do anything) it asks for a username and password which I have no idea what they are.

Doesn't the GitHub Dekstop use the same git commands under the hood and therefore the aws credential helper for git?

I'd also like to know if there is a better way to manage which profile to use with git other than running `git config --global credential.helper '!aws2 --profile my-profile codecommit credential-helper $@'` every time I want to deal with a repo from different account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From IAM, click Users(on the left bar) -> find and click your user -> Security credentials tab -> scroll down to "HTTPS Git credentials for AWS CodeCommit" -> in the Actions dropdown, you can reset your password.

Also, below that Actions dropdown, you'll see your username listed.

Comment: AWS SSO users (as mentioned in question) will not show up on IAM Users list

Comment: Where would these credentials be saved? Github Desktop has only 2 options, github.com or GitHub Enterprise. CodeCommit is neither of them

Answer (score 0):

If we can get https credentials for AWS codecommit via IAM. We can save it in github desktop and access repository

But if Codecommit is accessed via AWS SSO profile, the only option is to set git config.
I am also unable to access codecommit from github desktop even after setting profile and credential helper